# adding new menu in Select (All,Inverted Selection) in Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco-share

I am newbie to the Alfresco.Now my requirement is how to add new menu[All(All pages)] in Select. wherever user perform search function lets say 250 results have found & user selects All in page 1 & its selecting only current page results and not selecting entire 250 records & then user goes page by page can edit the properties for the entire 250 records.in the new functionality if user selects [All(All pages)] then all records should be selected & edit the properties for 250 records at one go.So I want to add new menu with All(All pages) & change the existing menu current labels as All(Current Page).How to achieve this functionality and what files need to changed.How should i know that which files are currently used?Is there any debugger can be used to know the files?

Alfresco Version
4.2.e

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess, is that if you go through [this previous version](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/tree/4.2.c) of [Jeff Potts' Tutorial](https://github.com/jpotts/alfresco-developer-series/) you will be able to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: In this scenario.I need to do the customization of the select menu.Do I need to use workflows, webscripts or Content?

Comment: I would recommend you follow at least the content and actions tutorials. What you are trying to do is a doclib action, but you will need ressources created in the first tutorial...

Comment: Once you have followed both tutorials, you can check [this documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/doclib-web-tier.html) as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is to edit label of that particular action in out of box property file.
You can find it under

```
<ALF_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages\slingshot.properties
```

This entry

**menu.select.all=All**

Change label here and it will be reflected.
NOTE: It is not best way to implement this. Ideally you need to override property file and change label

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that only the items shown on the page have been loaded. This means that the metadata for the items not shown on the page won't be available. The metadata of each node is used to evaluate it's applicability to any action. If the node is locked or has had its permissions changed then it won't be possible to edit it. This is why "all" only means all items on the current page of data.